# Can I substitute a variable from a java file with a link using struts tags in jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a string which is getting set in a struts action class as below:

```
public class myAction extends ActionSupport {

public String execute() throws Exception {
String sub= "login/signup";
String str="Click to redirect to" +sub+"to access site features";
}
```

I want to put this string in my jsp page so that it substitutes the sub-string with the actual hyperlink and when user click that url it goes to the login page.

I can embed the url using `s:url` tag in my jsp page and link it to sub variable but how can I put the url within the string so that it displays following text on my web-page:

```
Click to redirect to login/signup to access site features
```

Please note my screen message is coming from the backend java file and cannot be hard coded in jsp file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your action class, you have to take two different variables; one for **hyperLink** which will be used in [anchor](/questions/tagged/anchor) tag; second **linkString** which will be used to display the text for the hyperlink. Follow my code :

**Action Class**

```
public class myAction extends ActionSupport {

   private String hyperLink;
   private String linkString;

   // getters and setters

   public String execute() throws Exception {
      this.setLinkString("login/signup");
      this.setHyperLink("testloginpage.html");
      return "success";
   }

}
```

Then in your **`struts.xml`**, you have to write your action mapping :

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="yourAction" class="myAction" method="execute">
     <result name="success">/YourJSPPage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Now to display the hyperlink along with the string, write following code in your [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp) page :

**JSP Page**

```
<p>
   Click to redirect to 
   <a href="<s:text name='hyperLink'/>">
      <s:text name="linkString"/>
   </a> to access site features
</p>
```

Comment: `s:text` doesn't print anything to the output